# Identifying best combination of values in an N by N matrix to maximize value of linear objective function in Python

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming, pulp

I have an array (I am presenting it as a dictionary) of shifts, where each row is an individual and each shift they qualify for can be multiple. I am using letters in the example to convey how the data matches up.  The actual data set is 0 or 1 for the letter representation i.e. 
shifts = {Bob: (A, C, E), George: (B, C), Steve: (B, C, E), Greg: (C), Jose:(B,E)}  essentially becoming [[(A, 0, C, 0, E),(0, B, C, 0, 0), (0, 0, C, 0, 0), (0, B, 0, D, E)]]

I have a quota for a quantity of individuals to fill each shift. 
An individual can not be assigned to 2 different shifts.

basically=> totalshifts = A=1 + B=1 + C=2 + E=1  => 5 total positions
constraints are A<=1:A>=0 , B<=1:B>=0, C<=2:C>=0, E<=1:E>=0

This is currently being solved in excel solver with simplex LP set to maximize.
I have been looking into utilizing scipy.optimize.linprog, but I am struggling to set this up correctly, or how to handle it when the input array comes up short for the required number of people for a shift.

I want the output to be where the individual is assiged the correct shift to maxamize the function for each shift, or to get as close to maximizing it, akin to the following:  Bob:A, George:B, Steve:C, Greg:C, Jose:E
essentially the answer matrix needs to be [(A, 0, 0, 0, 0),(0, B, 0, 0, 0),(0 , 0, C, 0 ,0), (0, 0, C, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, E)] such that I can reference back to the correct candidate with the correct shift.  This is a simple case, it's more on the order of 10 different shifts and 100's-1000's of individuals.

Excel Example: Don't have 10 rep to post images currently
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIPUo.jpg

Comment: This post is a missing a lot of information and is hard to read. But to give you a hint: this looks like an integer-programming problem to me and there is no solver for that within scipy. linprog will not help. I also don't think your excel-solver approach is a pure simplex approach, because it's not possible. Try to improve your question a bit!

Comment: It does work.  An array is made of all the employees, and the shifts. in excel it is a column of names, the cells sum the row across all the shifts.  this column of summed cells is then constrained to be not greater than 1.  Those cells are summed as the ultimate target.  The solver is set to vary the array of shift values, to maximize the total assigned number for each value for each shift, such that the single summed value does not become greater than 1.

Comment: Then you should add more information and clean up the question a bit. If your previous approach has a more formal description/code, then add it. If just simplex was used, then it should be easy to use linprog. And maybe add an example.